# Navigator and scroll both misbehaving in stock highcharts

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts, stock-highcharts

I have multiple lines to be displayed. When I load stock chart for the first time, navigator and scroll window's behavior is okay.

**DEMO** : https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-a8exhr?file=index.js

But when I press `1m, 1d, 1h` etc options, it starts misbehaving and doesn't draw two lines in navigator.

Currently my settings are,

```
 series: seriesOptions,
  navigator: {
    series: [
      {
        data: seriesOptions[0].data,
      },
    ]
```

I tried with,

```
 series: seriesOptions,
  navigator: {
    series: seriesOptions
    ]
```

but it is misbehaving.

I want it to behave like this : https://www.highcharts.com/demo/stock/compare

**NOTE**: I'm using lazy loading feature when I click on `1d, 1m` etc options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options for `navigator` and `series` from the `chartOptions.js` file are lost because of merging. You can disable `dataGrouping` in `plotOptions` and  move `navigator` config to one place.

```
  plotOptions: {
      series: {
          showInNavigator: true,
          dataGrouping: {
            enabled: false
        }
      }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-jjbgne?file=chartOptions.js,index.js